# .htaccess Error Msg: I can see it but I couldnt write to it! required permission

Tags: apache

I already search the web to find the solution for this I am using **joomla** as **CMS** and using **DMC firewall** but when I logged in in my administrator account I always see this error message **".htaccess I can see it but I couldnt write to it**" I am using **xampp** and **linux** as a webserver I already change the permission from 777 to 755 to 644 but I still get the error

Comment: What does `ls -la .htaccess` show? (for the correct access file that is :) ).

Comment: Also for future information changing permissions from 777 -> 775 -> 644 is removing permissions.  If you are having trouble writing a file, restricting permissions (read, write, or execute) for the group and user is not the way to go.

Comment: now the permission is 644 (rw-r-r). Do i need to configure my httpd.conf?

Comment: actually there is two files the first one is backup.htaccess and the second one is htaccess.txt